# Having a small problem with my flutter app. I'm unable to print location value on the screen. What should be done?

Tags: flutter, dart, weather

I'm trying to create a flutter weather app. It's my first time creating an app and learning to code. So far it's good, but I have one slight problem. I'm unable to print or show the location on the screen. İt's supposed to be at the very top of the devices screen.

When I run the app on an Emulator, it does show the current location of the device. But when I run the app on a physical device (OnePlus 5 and Galaxy S10), It doesn't show the location.

As you will see below, I'm also unable to print the location into the console.

I have 2 .dart files. Code in both files are provided below.

Other than that everything works perfectly. No errors are being shown.

What am I missing or what have I done wrong. Thanks for the help.

**main.dart:**

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'GetLocation.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(AuraWeather());
}

class AuraWeather extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AuraWeatherState createState() => _AuraWeatherState();
}

class _AuraWeatherState extends State<AuraWeather> {

  var apiKey = '******************************';
  var description;
  var city;
  var maxTemp;
  var minTemp;
  var temp;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getLocation();

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage(displayBackground()),
          ),
        ),
        child: BackdropFilter(
          filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaY: 2, sigmaX: 2),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
            child: Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              body: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            '$city',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 35,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: Icon(
                          FontAwesomeIcons.locationArrow,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 80),
                        child: Text(
                          '$temp' + '°',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 50,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.wb_sunny,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: 100,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        '$maxTemp ° | $minTemp °',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Text(
                      '$description',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: FlatButton(
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.refresh,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: 40,
                      ),
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(
                          () {
                            getLocation();
                          },
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // display background images based on current time
  displayBackground() {
    var now = DateTime.now();
    final currentTime = DateFormat.jm().format(now);
    if (currentTime.contains('AM')) {
      return 'images/Blood.png';
    } else if (currentTime.contains('PM')) {
      return 'images/Sun.png';
    }
  }

  //getLocation
  void getLocation() async {
    Getlocation getlocation = Getlocation();
    await getlocation.getCurrentLocation();

    print(getlocation.latitude);
    print(getlocation.longitude);
    print(getlocation.city);
    city = getlocation.city;
    getTemp(getlocation.latitude, getlocation.longitude);
  }

  //Get current temp
  Future<void> getTemp(double lat, double lon) async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(
        'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=$lat&lon=$lon&appid=$apiKey&units=metric');
    //print(response.body);

    var dataDecoded = jsonDecode(response.body);
    description = dataDecoded['weather'][0]['description'];

    temp = dataDecoded['main']['temp'];
    temp = temp.toInt();

    maxTemp = dataDecoded['main']['temp_max'];
    maxTemp = maxTemp.toInt();

    minTemp = dataDecoded['main']['temp_min'];
    minTemp = minTemp.toInt();

    print(temp);
  }
}
```

**GetLocation.dart:**

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class Getlocation {
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    String city;
    //Get current location
    Future<void> getCurrentLocation() async {
        try {
            Position position = await Geolocator()
                    .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
            latitude = position.latitude;
            longitude = position.longitude;

            city = await getCityName(position.latitude, position.longitude);
        } catch (e) {
            print(e);
        }
    }

    //Get city name
    Future<String> getCityName(double lat, double lon) async {
        List<Placemark> placemark =
        await Geolocator().placemarkFromCoordinates(lat, lon);
        print('city name is: ${placemark[0].locality}');
        return placemark[0].locality;
    }
}
```

**Console window:**

```
Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device ONEPLUS A5000...
Reloaded 0 of 587 libraries in 251ms.
I/flutter (13296): city name is: 
I/flutter (13296): 41.0179339
I/flutter (13296): 28.6239036
I/flutter (13296): 
I/flutter (13296): 20
```

**Pubspec:**

```
name: com
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number

     separated by a +.
    # Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
    # build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
    # In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
    # Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
    # In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
    # Read more about iOS versioning at
    # https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
    version: 1.0.0+1

    environment:
      sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

    dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter

      # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
      # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
      cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
      intl: ^0.16.1
      geolocator: ^5.3.1
      http: ^0.12.0+4
      sunrise_sunset: ^1.0.2
      font_awesome_flutter: ^8.5.0

    dev_dependencies:
      flutter_test:
        sdk: flutter


    # For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
    # following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

    # The following section is specific to Flutter.
    flutter:

      # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
      # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
      # the material Icons class.
      uses-material-design: true

      # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
      assets:
        - images/
      #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

      # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
      # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

      # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
      # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

      # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
      # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
      # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
      # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
      # example:
      # fonts:
      #   - family: Schyler
      #     fonts:
      #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
      #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
      #         style: italic
      #   - family: Trajan Pro
      #     fonts:
      #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
      #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
      #         weight: 700
      #
      # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
      # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

**AndroidManifest:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.auraweather">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="auraweather"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Possible thing is that you might have given the permission but check whether your location is turned on in your device

Comment: @FrontEndOnDemand My location is turned on. It's on High Accuracy. I am able to get the weather forecast and everything but the location name isn't showing.

Answer (score 0):

its seems good code, but something is absent here.

first: where is your location permission request?
Second : why dont use initState for override

> getLocation();

and in final step, u must implement all requirements for Geolocator plugin.

check these steps and update me in comment.

Comment: 1 - location permission request in inside the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: main.dart file, inside the the first container there is 'Text' widget. The text '$city' isn't being printed on the device. Also in GetLocation.dart file, there is a print function that prints "City name is   ". City name is not being printed.